# How do I organize a list by calendar date on a single Confluence page?

Tags: jira, confluence

I'm trying to store a list of errors detected in various production logs per day on a Confluence page.

Currently we create a docx file for one weeks worth of results and upload it to the page. I would like some macro or technique to compactly organize this data without uploads or giant copy-pastes.

Ideally, I want to be able to click on a particular date to display just the list of issues saved for that day. The lists will be short, 10-20 lines.

Edit for clarification:

Imagine a daily report getting generated:

```
[Log 1 name]: 1 error  
[Log 2 name]: 10 errors  
[Log 3 name]: 24 errors  
[Log 4 name]: 7 errors
```

The person in charge of log monitoring will be adding the day's numbers every day in a new column (to an attached excel file? inline table?). I want some way to display this information by date in a concise way on a single confluence page. Ideally, the user selects a date, and the the above described list for that day is presented.

I would like this to be scalable for the long term, so a table with thousands of rows or columns visible would not be a good look. Hence the desire to view information based on date.

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do. How is JIRA involved? How do the errors in the log relate to JIRA? What does the docx file have to do with "clicking on a date to display just the list of issues saved for that day"?

Comment: @GlennV , please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with **ankit**, it isn't totally clear what you are looking for and it does not seem to be JIRA related. Confluence version and available plug-ins may be relevant too.

Off-hand I'd look to script the entire thing (bash, PowerShell, etc. depending on OS and organizational abilities). The scripting solution should facilitate grouping/sorting. I'd look to 'push' content into Confluence from the scripting solution directly leveraging Confluence's REST API. The Confluence Code Block macro (collapse = true) is one way you could 'hide' a day's "report" so that it isn't visible unless the user opts to "Expand source".

And, beware the Confluence REST API. Know your Confluence version and make sure you reference the applicable API documentation.